# How to define a custom name for delegate method in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a model with a delegate method,

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :meta_sm2

  delegate :next_repetition,
           to: :meta_sm2
end
```

Because the underlying model (currently is `meta_sm2`) might change in the future, so I would like to make the delegate method `next_repetition` to a custom name, like `priority` for example.

How can I defined a custom name delegate method, so that I can call the `next_repetition` like `card.priority`?

Comment: How would you like to call the custom name? I.e. considering I have a object from `Card` class called `card`.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use alias_method to achieve this.

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :meta_sm2

  delegate :next_repetition,
           to: :meta_sm2

alias_method :priority, :next_repetition

end
```